# Не записываются объекты в массив

Tags: java, массивы, объекты, запись

Проблема с записью объектов в массив, которые создаются из полей вводимых в консоль или с выводом через метод getStatus();

Класс Main

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

static Employer[] employers = new Employer[1];

public static void main(String[] args) {

    write(employers);

    show(employers);

}


public static void write(Employer[] employers) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        for (int i = 0; i < employers.length; i++){

            System.out.println("Enter surname: ");
            String surname = scan.next();
            System.out.println("Enter name: ");
            String name = scan.next();
            System.out.println("Enter ID number: ");
            long idnum = scan.nextLong();
            System.out.println("Enter year: ");
            int year = scan.nextByte();
            System.out.println("Enter payment: ");
            double payment = scan.nextDouble();
            System.out.print("\n");

            employers[i] = new Employer(surname, name, idnum, year, payment);
        }

}

public static void show(Employer[] employers){

    System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------------");
    System.out.printf("%15s | %10s | %11s | %4s | %7s", "Surname" , "Name", "ID number", "Year", "Payment");
    System.out.println("\n" + "-----------------------------------------------------------");

    for(int i = 0; i < employers.length; i++)
        employers[i].getStatus();

    System.out.println("\n" + "-----------------------------------------------------------");
}
```

Класс Employer

```
public class Employer {

String surname;
String name;
long idnum;
int year;
double payment;

public Employer(String surname, String name, long idnum, int year, double payment){

    this.surname = this.surname;
    this.name = this.name;
    this.idnum = this.idnum;
    this.year = this.year;
    this.payment = this.payment;

}

public String getSurname() {
    return surname;
}

public void setSurname(String surname) {
    this.surname = surname;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public long getIdnum() {
    return idnum;
}

public void setIdnum(long idnum) {
    this.idnum = idnum;
}

public int getYear() {
    return year;
}

public void setYear(int year) {
    this.year = year;
}

public double getPayment() {
    return payment;
}

public void setPayment(double payment) {
    this.payment = payment;
}

public void getStatus() {

    System.out.printf("%15s | %10s | %11d | %4d | %.1f" , getSurname(), getName(), getIdnum(), getYear(), getPayment());
    System.out.print("\n");

}
}
```

Comment: Конструктор `Employer` исправьте, присваиваете свои же поля экземпляра вместо аргументов.

Comment: Cпасибо, не знаю как сам не увидел)))